# Upload file Android org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity : Bad Request Error

Tags: java, android

The following code is giving Bad Request Error, any solution or fault in the code.

```
MultipartEntity entityPost = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

entityPost.addPart("data_1", new StringBody(String.valueOf(feedbackId), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));         
entityPost.addPart("file_1", new FileBody(__file));

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/webservice.asmx/method");
httppost.setEntity(entityPost);
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

HttpResponse __response = HttpManager.httpClient().execute(httppost);
```

WebService:

```
public String method() {    
    try {   
        System.Web.HttpContext postContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

        string data = postContext.Request.Form["data_1"].ToString();

        System.Web.HttpFileCollection files = postContext.Request.Files;        
        System.Web.HttpPostedFile = files[0];

        //etc etc

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //
    }
}
```

Error :

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: and where is the web service code?

Comment: properly elaborate your question

Comment: Bad Request : 400 is client side request error
Exception occurred before it entered webservice.

The webservice code has been tested using normal html multipart/form-data

If there is any error on webservice it would give 500+ error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Book Pro Android 3 by Satya Komatineni, Dave MacLean, Sayed Y. Hashimi.
External library is added:

**Commons IO**: http//commons.apache.org/io/

**Mime4j**: http//james.apache.org/mime4j/

**HttpMime**: http//hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (inside of HttpClient)

It works fine with same webservice created before.

```
File file = new File(filePath);     
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://mysomewebserver.com/services/doSomething.do");


byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new
ByteArrayInputStream(data), "filename");
StringBody sb1 = new StringBody("some text goes here");
StringBody sb2 = new StringBody("some text goes here too");
MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
multipartContent.addPart("uploadedFile", isb);
multipartContent.addPart("one", sb1);
multipartContent.addPart("two", sb2);

postRequest.setEntity(multipartContent);
HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(postRequest);
response.getEntity().getContent().close();
```

But there is warning that MultipartEntity is deprecreated. I am not very much sure about that.